# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("="col-md-4 control-label" for="idNome">Nome: </label>

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-forms

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("="col-md-4 control-label" for="idNome">Nome:

**app.module.ts:**

```
 import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
   @NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent], 
  imports: [
   ...
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**a app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**a atendimento.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AtendimentoRoutingModule } from './atendimento-routing.module';
import { AtendimentoComponent } from './atendimento/atendimento.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AtendimentoRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [AtendimentoComponent]
})
export class AtendimentoModule { }
```

**and atendimento.component.ts:**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AtendimentoService } from '../atendimento.service';

import { Cliente } from '../../cliente/Cliente'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-atendimento',
  templateUrl: './atendimento.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./atendimento.component.css'],
  providers: [AtendimentoService, Cliente]
})
export class AtendimentoComponent implements OnInit {
```

Comment: Post your HTML code

Comment: <div class="col-md-5">
          <input [(ngModel)]="cliente.nome" type="text" name="idNome" class="form-control label-md" required="">
      </div>

Comment: do you have BrowserModule under imports in app.module.ts

Comment: i have:  BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: error is from somewhere else in the form, can you add whole template to your question

Comment: The error happens in this line, there is no other [(ngModel)] throughout the project

Comment: but your question shows different line

Comment: Oh really? Sorry, I did not post the whole error.
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("="col-md-4 control-label" for="idNome">Nome: </label>
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <input [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="cliente.nome" type="text" name="idNome" class="form-control label-md" required="">

Comment: you need to add FormsModule to the a atendimento.module.ts as well, since your component is a part of atendimento.module.ts

Comment: worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add **`FormsModule`** to the a **`atendimento.module.ts`** as well, since your component is a part of **`AtendimentoModule`**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AtendimentoRoutingModule } from './atendimento-routing.module';
import { AtendimentoComponent } from './atendimento/atendimento.component';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AtendimentoRoutingModule,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [AtendimentoComponent]
})
export class AtendimentoModule { }
```